# Multi-condition rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a site with areas that require forced SSL mode and then forced to non-SSL for the rest.

I have started with the following rules:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/tourism/bookings/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/tourism/bookings/$1 [R,L]
  RewriteRule ^/?bookings/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/bookings/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bookings
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tourism/bookings
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [L,R,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, the above works - but the SSL mode obviously interprets /includes/* to force it to non-SSL... is there an adjustment to the above to allow me to force ALL content except the two above (but any dependencies, like JS / CSS includes to follow the current protocol)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude other things besides `/bookings` and `/tourism/bookings` then simply exclude them in conditions.

Also, you don't need the `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` condition since that virtual host is always going to be non-HTTPS:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/tourism/bookings/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/tourism/bookings/$1 [R,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/?bookings/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/bookings/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bookings
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tourism/bookings
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [L,R,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```